# Raising noncustom events in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, events, flash-cs5, event-dispatching

I'm using ActionScript 3 in Flash Professional and I'd like my class to raise an event, not a custom event but an existing one. I've set up my class so that it extends EventDispatcher. In the documentation http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html the example declares a custom event by adding a static String variable:

`class CustomDispatcher extends EventDispatcher {`

```
        public static var ACTION:String = "action";
```

I assume that enables:

`dispatcher.addEventListener(CustomDispatcher.ACTION, actionHandler);`

or at least auto-complete when you've typed 'dispatcher.addEventListener(' into the Flash Professional IDE.

But lots of classes that raise events raise a mixture of existing noncustom events. For example if you have an instance of a flash.netFileReference and type

`fileRef.addEventListener(`

a long list of potential events to listen for is given including DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA, Event.SELECT, HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, etc.

If I want my class to be registered to raise those existing events, what code do I need? Preferably so that the IDE knows instances of my class may raise the event and suggests them in the addEventListener auto-complete/intellisense list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the events show up in the intellisense, you need to register them using the [Event metatag](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html):

```
[Event(name="eventName", type="package.eventType")]
```

Add this just before the classes that dispatches this event.

Comment: Thanks Laurent, that's what I was after.